# Python logging for custom namespace misses prefix

Tags: python

I tried to enable [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) for my python library. I want all logs to go into my custom subset `my_logger` instead of `root`. So this is what I tried:

```
import logging
my_logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
my_logger.warning("my hello!")
logging.warning("hello!")
```

And for some reason my custom logger didn't output subset name (`my_logger`) in front of it.

```
my hello!
WARNING:root:hello!
```

A simple change of the order of root and my loggers fixed the issue:

```
import logging
logging.warning("hello!")
my_logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
my_logger.warning("my hello!")
```

Output

```
WARNING:root:hello!
WARNING:my_logger:my hello!
```

I do not ever want to use a root logger at all. Is it possible to get `WARNING:my_logger` prefix to my output without logging to the root logger first?

Comment: You should call `logging.basicConfig` to configure the logging system before using it. (Though if you're writing a library, it should never call it by itself.)

Comment: @AKX Yeah, so that is the issue. I want to specialize logs to my library namespace to make it clear for the user where they came from, but I can't actually use `logging.basicConfig` as it is supposed to be used only by the user. Looks like a no-win situation.

Comment: No, it's not. Just use the specialized logger - your user is responsible for configuring logging.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `logging` module is doing first-time configuration during the first call. You can do that first to get it out of the way before using your logger:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig() # do the configuration
my_logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
my_logger.warning("my hello!")
logging.warning("hello!")
```

Result:

```
WARNING:my_logger:my hello!
WARNING:root:hello!
```

For a library that you expect others to import, this should be done by the code importing the module instead of the library.

Comment: A library should never call basicConfig.